# Symfony2: ajax call redirection if session timedout

Tags: ajax, symfony, session

I have a working dashboard with ajax request. I fire an ajax request on some events which will update a part of the dashboard. But if the session has expired, the part will be refreshed with the login page. How can i do a redirection after the ajax call if the session has expired ?

My ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $(this).data('path'),
    data: { datas : {
         /* some datas */
    }},
    success: function(data){
        $('#mydivtorefresh').html(data); 
    },
    error: function(){
        showFlash();
    },
});
```

and my controller :

```
public function myControllerAction(Request $request)
{
    /* some logic */
    return $this->render('my/template/toUp.html.twig',array('results' => $results));
```

All is working well, but if my session expires and i call this ajax request, i will get the login page in the '#mydivtorefresh' instead of a global redirection. I tried with eventListener or with AjaxError callback but with no success. Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a working solution :

Add a function in my global controller which check if session is still active and responds with "ok" if yes, "ko" if not.

```
public function pingAction()
{
    $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
    if ($securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED') || $securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
        return new Response("ok");
    }
    return new Response("ko");
}
```

and i check it every times an ajax call is fired using the preFilter jquery event :

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    if(originalOptions.data == "CHECKPING"){
        return;
    }
    $.get( Routing.generate('el_ping'), "CHECKPING", function( res ) {
        if(res == "ko"){
            window.location.replace(Routing.generate('fos_user_security_login'));
        }
    });
});
```